# How does having smaller values for parameters help in preventing over-fitting?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

To reduce the problem of over-fitting in linear regression in machine learning , it is suggested to modify the cost function by including squares of parameters. This results in smaller values of the parameters.

This is not at all intuitive to me. How can having smaller values for parameters result in simpler hypothesis and help prevent over-fitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit more complicated. It depends very much on the algorithm you are using.

To make an easy but slightly stupid example. Instead of optimising the parameter of the function

```
  y = a*x1 + b*x2
```

you could also optimising the parameters of

```
  y = 1/a * x1 + 1/b * x2
```

Obviously if you minimise in the former case the you need to maximise them in the latter case.

The fact that for most algorithm minimising the square of the parameters comes from **computational learning theory**.

Let's assume for the following you want to learn a function

```
 f(x) = a + bx + c * x^2 + d * x^3 +....
```

One can argue that a function were only a is different from zero is **more likely** than a function, where a and b are different form zero and so on.
Following **Occams razor** (If you have two hypothesis explaining your data, the simpler is more likely the right one), you should prefer a hypothesis where more of you parameters are zero.

To give an example lets say your data points are (x,y) = {(-1,0),(1,0)}
Which function would you prefer

```
f(x) = 0
```

or

```
f(x) = -1 +  1*x^2
```

Extending this a bit you can go from parameters which are zero to parameters which are small.

If you want to try it out you can sample some data points from a linear function and add a bit of gaussian noise. If you want to find a perfect polynomial fit you need a pretty complicated function with typically pretty large weights. However, if you apply regularisation you will come close to your data generating function.

But if you want to set your reasoning on rock-solid theoretical foundations I would recommend to apply **Baysian statistics**. The idea there is that you define a probability distribution over regression functions. That way you can define yourself what a "probable" regression function is.

(Actually Machine Learning by Tom Mitchell contains a pretty good and more detailed explanation)

Answer (score 5):

I put together a rather contrived example, but hopefully it helps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge, Lasso
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
```

First build a linear dataset, with a training and test split. 5 in each

```
X,y, c = datasets.make_regression(10,1, noise=5, coef=True, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, train_size=5)
```

[image: Original Data]

Fit the data with a fifth order polynomial with no regularization.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('poly',  PolynomialFeatures(5)),
        ('model', Ridge(alpha=0.))  # alpha=0 indicates 0 regularization.
    ])

pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Looking at the coefficients

```
pipeline.named_steps['model'].coef_
pipeline.named_steps['model'].intercept_

# y_pred = -12.82 + 33.59 x + 292.32 x^2 - 193.29 x^3 - 119.64 x^4 + 78.87 x^5
```

[image: No Regularization]

Here the model touches all the training point, but has high coefficients and does not touch the test points.

Let's try again, but change our L2 regularization

```
pipeline.set_params(model__alpha=1)
```

[image: With regularization]

```
y_pred = 6.88 + 26.13 x + 16.58 x^2 + 12.47 x^3 + 5.86 x^4 - 5.20 x^5
```

Here we see a smoother shape, with less wiggling around. It no longer touches all the training points, but it is a much smoother curve. The coefficients are smaller due to the regularization being added.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the squares to your function (so from linear to polynomial) takes care that you can draw a curve instead of just a straight line.

Example of polynomial function:

```
y=q+t1*x1+t2*x2^2;
```

> Adding this however can lead to a result which follows the test data too much with as result that new data is matched to close to the test data. Adding more and more polynomials (3rd, 4th orders). So when adding polynomials you always have to watch out that the data is not becoming overfitted.

To get more insight in this, draw some curves in a spreadsheet and see how the curves change following your data.

Comment: But how does adding the squares in cost function get us simpler hypothesis?

i didnt get you here.